# Monitoring catalina.out [Logfile with multiple Lines]

Tags: tomcat, monitoring, logfile

we want to monitor the Tomcat catalina.log.
But each Error-Message has mutliple Lines. 
Our Logfileadapter from Monitoring-Tool (HPOM) only works with single-line Messages.
Does anyone have a solution for it?

Example:

```
   15.07.2015 15:09:59 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextDestroyed
INFO: WSSERVLET13: JAX-WS context listener destroyed

from here ---->  
15.07.2015 15:10:01 org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener destroy
WARNUNG: Error unregistering MBeanServerDelegate
    java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener.destroy(MapperListener.java:162)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.stop(Connector.java:1180)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:593)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:616)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:659)**
to here ----->

15.07.2015 15:10:01 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
15.07.2015 15:10:01 org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector stop
SCHWERWIEGEND: Coyote connector has not been started
```

Comment: May I ask whether your tool would be able to extract meaningful information using only the first line of the stack trace?

Comment: I want to read the Line with the date. At preprocessing I have now to detect the lines between the line with date and the next line with another date.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it as follows:

```
sed -n '/15.07.2015 15:10:01 org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener destroy/,/^[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/p' catalina.log|head -n -1
```

But here SED was used. So it doesnt work in Windows.